# providing structs in class diagram

Tags: struct, uml

I have  struct chartManager which contains struct of series and struct series which contain struct of points. and they are all in Chart class.
something like this

```
Class Chart
{
protected:
  struct points
  {
    int seriesPoints[10];
  };

  struct series
  {
    points seriespoints;
    char seriesName[20];
  };

  struct pageManager
  {
    char chartName[20];
    series totalSeries[5];
  };
};
```

How do i show this in class diagram??

Comment: I see that you did not mark an answer as solution. Maybe I can improve my answer, if you need some additional informations.

Answer (score 2):

A good answer is : never go from specific language to UML :)

Nevertheless, composition/aggregation with cardinality is for me the way to go (a struct is pretty the same as a class).

Answer (score 2):

I see this is a old post, but maybe I can help someone with my answer. 
The best way to describe the above example is with **"Nesting"** connections.
Composition or Aggregation prerequisite that they are independent and not within the class itself.